# How to get dynamically loaded HTML tags with specific class from the page using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic-data

I am adding some HTML tags using JavaScript like this:

```
function createTag(text) {
    if (text != '') {
        text = text.replace(',', '');
        if (/^\s+$/.test(text) == false) {
            var tag = $('<div class="tags">' + text + '<a class="delete">X</a></div>');
            tag.insertBefore($('input.tag_list'), $('input.tag_list'));
            $('input.tag_list').val('');
        }
    }
```

I want to get the values in the `<div class="tags">` tags from all over the page. How can I do it?

Also how can I restrict the number of dynamically created tags of these types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the tags and use the `map()` function to return an array.  Within the function supplied to `map()` remove the `a` from a cloned tag.

```
var tags = $(".tags").map(function(){
    var clone = $(this).clone();
    $(clone).find("a").remove("a");
    return clone.text();
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ELxW4/

You could make life somewhat easier by wrapping the values in `span` tags:

```
<div class="tags"><span>javascript</span><a class="delete">X</a></div>
<div class="tags"><span>java</span><a class="delete">X</a></div>
<div class="tags"><span>jquery</span><a class="delete">X</a></div>
```

Then get the tags using:

```
var tags = $(".tags").map(function(){
    return $(this).find("span").text();
});
```

Comment: Thank @kevin. But I am confused with the use of `clone()`. Can you explain me your JS code? As I am not so good at JS.

Comment: You need to obtain the value within the `div.tags`, however the `div` contains both a value such as `javascript,java,jquery` as well as an `<a/>`.  Well I'm sure you don't want that `<a/>` tag included in the values.  So I clone the element, which makes an exact copy, then remove the `<a/>` from the clone, so I can simply retrieve the value.  This leaves the original element untouched, while allowing me to simply call `.text()` to get the value inside the `div`.